# Getting system info using WMI

Tags: visual-c++, wmi, system-information

Take this code:

```
SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo{};
GetSystemInfo(&siSysInfo);

strHardwareInfo.AppendFormat(L"  %s: %u\r\n", L"Number of processors", siSysInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors);
strHardwareInfo.AppendFormat(L"  %s: %u\r\n", L"Page size", siSysInfo.dwPageSize);
strHardwareInfo.AppendFormat(L"  %s: %lx\r\n", L"Minimum application address", siSysInfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress);
strHardwareInfo.AppendFormat(L"  %s: %lx\r\n", L"Maximum application address", siSysInfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress);
strHardwareInfo.AppendFormat(L"  %s: %u\r\n", L"Active processor mask", siSysInfo.dwActiveProcessorMask);
```

What are the WMI equivalents? I know the first one is:

- `Win32_Processor. NumberOfLogicalProcessors`

The others?

---

I thought that `Win32_PageFileUsage.AllocatedBaseSize` might have been the equivalent of `dwPageSize` in the structure. But it is not:

- 2048 (`Win32_PageFileUsage.AllocatedBaseSize`)
- 4096 (`SYSTEM_INFO.dwPageSize`)

---

For example, `GetSysInfo` returns:

```
  Number of processors: 8
  Page Size: 4096
  Minimum application address: 10000
  Maximum application address: fffeffff
  Active processor mask: 255
```

But msinfo says:

[image]

Don't get it ...